# How should one prepare the stack when calling ExitProcess?

Tags: windows, assembly, 64-bit, masm

I'm trying to learn how to invoke operating system functions in assembly and have gotten an example worked out that will create and then close a file (deleting it file on close). While researching the usage of `ExitProcess` I came across some example that clean up the stack and some that don't; even more confusing is that things seem to work with or without a clean up step...

What is the proper way to handle the stack in this situation?

```
extern CloseHandle : proc
extern CreateFileA : proc
extern ExitProcess : proc

include FileAccess.inc
include FileDisposition.inc
include FileFlag.inc
include FileShare.inc

.data

filePath byte "C:\Temp\test123.txt",0

.code

Main PROC
    sub rsp, 48h                                                      ; align with 16 while simultaneously making room on the stack for the "home space" and any parameters
    lea rcx, filePath                                                 ; put address of file name into parameter slot 0
    mov rdx, FILE_ACCESS_READ                                         ; put access mode into parameter slot 1
    mov r8, FILE_SHARE_READ                                           ; put share mode into parameter slot 2
    xor r9, r9                                                        ; put security attributes into parameter slot 3
    mov qword ptr [((rsp + 48h) - 28h)], FILE_DISPOSITION_CREATE      ; put disposition into parameter slot 4
    mov qword ptr [((rsp + 48h) - 20h)], FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE    ; put flags into parameter slot 5
    mov qword ptr [((rsp + 48h) - 18h)], 0                            ; put template handle into parameter slot 6
    call CreateFileA                                                  ; create file handle
    mov rcx, rax                                                      ; move file handle into parameter slot 0
    call CloseHandle                                                  ; close file handle
    add rsp, 48h                                                      ; free all space that was reserved on the stack
    xor ecx, ecx                                                      ; set return value to zero
    call ExitProcess
Main ENDP

END
```

Comment: not need any *clean up the stack*, just call `ExitProcess` like any other api. and better use another declarations: `extern __imp_ExitProcess : QWORD` and `call __imp_ExitProcess` and so on for every imported api - add prefix `__imp_` to name, declare it as `QWORD` instead `proc`

Comment: @RbMm Can you explain all that in a proper answer and I'll accept?

Comment: you current code formal mistake - stack is not aligned on 16*n before call `ExitProcess` but some time this have not lead to mistake, some time can be crash. you not need `add rsp, 48h` here. again `ExitProcess` api and need be called like all another api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the [`ExitProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess) usual function (windows api) and must be called with common calling convention for x64. in particular stack must be [*maintained 16-byte aligned*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/stack-usage?view=vs-2017)
so call `ExitProcess` like any other api. the `add rsp, 48h` instruction before `call ExitProcess` is wrong

also some general notes:
the imported api always called indirect - if you want call `SomeApi` - declare variable (code for x64)

```
extern __imp_SomeApi : QWORD
```

and call

```
call __imp_SomeApi
```

if we declare

```
extern SomeApi : proc
```

and do

```
call SomeApi
```

the linker create stub

```
SomeApi:
jmp  qword ptr __imp_SomeApi
```

so better direct use `__imp_SomeApi` form.

also always much better use *W* instead *A* api form. so all code can look like

```
FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE = 04000000h
CREATE_ALWAYS = 2
FILE_SHARE_READ = 1
GENERIC_READ = 080000000h
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1

extern __imp_ExitProcess : QWORD
extern __imp_CreateFileW : QWORD
extern __imp_CloseHandle : QWORD

WSTRING macro text
    FORC arg, text
    DW '&arg'
    ENDM
    DW 0
endm

.const
    ALIGN 2
filePath: WSTRING <C:\Temp\test123.txt>

.code
Main proc
    sub rsp, 48h                                                        
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 30h], 0                                        
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 28h], FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE                
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 20h], CREATE_ALWAYS                            
    xor r9, r9                                                          
    mov r8, FILE_SHARE_READ                                             
    mov rdx, GENERIC_READ                                               
    lea rcx, filePath                                                   
    call __imp_CreateFileW 
    cmp rax, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
    je @@0                                           
    mov rcx, rax                                                        
    call __imp_CloseHandle  
@@0:                                           
    xor ecx, ecx                                                        
    call __imp_ExitProcess 
    add rsp, 48h                                                        
    ret                                                    
Main endp

end
```

Comment: Thank you. Are `add rsp, 48h` and `ret` required after `call __imp_ExitProcess`? I've seen many many examples where those last two instructions are omitted; just want to learn what the best practice here is and why.

Comment: @Kittoes, ExitProcess never returns, so it makes no difference what you put after it.